# Disabling ECN: Netsh: incorrect paramater when executing via SaltStack cmd.run

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2, saltstack, netsh

I'm attempting to mass [disable Explicit Network Congestion Notification](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20204.how-to-enable-and-disable-explicit-congestion-notification-in-windows.aspx) on a group of Windows Server 2012r2 servers hosted in AWS EC2.  I'm using the Salt Stack configuration management tool.  When I execute the command to disable ECN locally, on a server from an elevated command prompt:

`netsh int tcp set global ecncapability=disabled`

it works correctly -- `ok`

When I execute it from the salt master:

`salt -G "os:windows" cmd.run 'netsh int tcp set global ecncapability=disabled'`

It returns

`Set global command failed on IPv4 The parameter is incorrect.`

Other netsh commands work correctly.  I've attempted [several other fixes](http://deinfotech.blogspot.com/2012/02/set-global-command-failed-on-ipv4.html), including executing with the netsh in C:\windows\system32\netsh.exe, as well as the C:\windows\sysWOW64\netsh.exe.  Neither work, both produce the same errors.I'm running Salt Master version 2016.11.4 Carbon.